# How much does the International Prototype Kilogramme weigh?

Tags: mass, si-units, metrology

From [some date in] 1889 to 20 May 2019 the International Prototype Kilogramme in Paris (called the *ur-kilogram* by German-influenced writers) weighed $1.000\,000\,00kg$. It seems very hard to find out how its mass has evolved since then and what it is now.

- What was its mass on 21 May 2019?
- What is its mass today?

A bonus would be to have an answer to the same question about the *Kilogramme des Archives* (its predecessor), assuming that it hasn’t been mislaid. A second-best would be to have an answer to the same question about the second-best standard masses in the USA, the UK and other countries.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Prototype_of_the_Kilogram#Stability_of_the_IPK

Comment: Thank you; but it doesn't mention any weighings of the IPK since 2019.

Comment: it says in the beginning "until 2019, when it was replaced by a new definition of the kilogram based on physical constants."  measured in different ways ;